# Case and Where logic appear similar but yield different results

Tags: sql, case, where-clause, teradata

I received a query from a coworker that has a `where` statement like the following:

```
where ...
and case
    when    AOS.aircft_out_of_srvc_reason_cd in ('L','H')
         or AOS.mntnc_stn_cd in ('TLE','DWH') then 'Y'
    else 'N' end ='N'
```

I figured I could take out the `case` if I changed it to the following

```
where ...
and not (   AOS.aircft_out_of_srvc_reason_cd in ('L','H')
         or AOS.mntnc_stn_cd in ('TLE','DWH'))
```

but this is somehow yielding less than 10% of the original number of records. To me, the logic in the two appears to be the same. Does anyone have any idea why Teradata is treating them differently?

Comment: Can you point out one example row that is selected by the first query, but not the second one?

Comment: Do any of the columns `aircft_out_of_srvc_reason_cd` and `mntnc_stn_cd` allow null values?

Comment: `OR` is good. It's negated by the `not (...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent logic for this:

```
where ... and
     (case when AOS.aircft_out_of_srvc_reason_cd in ('L', 'H') or
                AOS.mntnc_stn_cd in ('TLE', 'DWH')
           then 'Y'
           else 'N'
      end) = 'N'
```

is essentially:

```
where . . . and
      AOS.aircft_out_of_srvc_reason_cd not in ('L', 'H') and
      AOS.mntnc_stn_cd not in ('TLE', 'DWH')
```

(which is the same as your `not` expression)

The only issue is if both of the columns are `NULL`, so you should include:

```
where . . . and
      ( (AOS.aircft_out_of_srvc_reason_cd not in ('L', 'H') and
         AOS.mntnc_stn_cd not in ('TLE', 'DWH') and
        ) or
        (AOS.aircft_out_of_srvc_reason_cd is null and AOS.mntnc_stn_cd is null)
      )
```

Comment: Yeah, I think the root cause of the issue are null values, even though Eric hasn't responded.

Comment: The columns in this part of the where were not in the original query. After including them, it became very obvious that the two columns were either both null or neither were null. I still don't understand though, does `null in (x,y,z) or null in (a,b,c)` return true?

Comment: @EricEdLohmar . . . No.  Almost any comparison that includes `NULL` returns `NULL` which is treated the same as false in a `WHERE` clause.